# How to avoid "No such file or directory" Error for `make clean` Makefile target

Tags: linux, makefile, rm

I have a Makefile that defines a .PHONY clean target for cleaning up .o files and executables, that target looks like:

```
...
.PHONY : clean
clean:
    rm $(addprefix $(vq_DIR),$(vq_OBJS)) \
       $(addprefix $(vq_DIR),vq) \
       $(addprefix $(covq_DIR),$(covq_OBJS)) \
       $(addprefix $(covq_DIR),covq) \
       $(addprefix $(covq_2_DIR),$(covq_2_OBJS)) \
       $(addprefix $(covq_2_DIR),covq_2) \
       $(addprefix $(covq_2_DIR),$(test_OBJS)) \
       $(addprefix $(covq_2_DIR),test)
```

Everything works as it should, but when some of these files do not exist, `rm` raises an Error (No such file or directory), and the output says that the Makefile target failed, when it clearly did what I wanted.

Is there a good way to basically tell the `rm` command to "remove these files if they exist, and don't complain if they don't"? I looked up the manpage for `rm`, and found no such flag.

Edit: I actually didn't notice the description of the `-f` flag in the manpage, this is the solution.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `rm -f` (or even better `$(RM)`, provided by built-in `make` rules, which can be found out using `make -p`) instead of `rm` in your `clean`rule.

Comment: Thank you! I actually must have skimmed over that option. The manpage says exactly what I need, i.e. `ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt`

Comment: Even better: use `$(RM)`, which is automatically defined by GNU Makefile.

Answer (score 7):

> rm -f

will FORCE and not output any error

Answer (score 4):

> When Targets Fail
>
> When a target is executed, it returns a status based on whether or not
> it was successful--if a target fails, then make will not execute any
> targets that depend on it. For instance, in the above example, if
> "clean" fails, then rebuild will not execute the "build" target.
> Unfortunately, this might happen if there is no core file to remove.
> Fortunately, this problem can be solved easily enough by including a
> minus sign in front of the command whose status should be ignored:
>
> ```
> clean:
>         -rm -f *.o core
> ```

~ http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/makefiles.html

Comment: It will not be ignored if you execute `make clean` though. It seems to me that it is only ignored if this target was a dependency to another target.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but here's another solution that worked with our quirky build environment:

```
if exist *.exe rm -f *.exe
```

Not output free, but reduced and exits cleanly:

```
# make clean
        if exist *.exe rm -f *.exe
```

I tried a lot of alternatives that all had issues before settling on this one.

Answer (score -1):

I've given up with rm.
The following command will remove files and dirs.

```
find . -delete
```

To remove only files or only dirs, there is the -type option:

```
# remove only files
find . -type f -delete


# remove only dirs
find . -type d -delete
```

Actually, I've create a little script (based on that snippet) named bomb that removes files without complaining: https://github.com/lingtalfi/bomb